# MBProgressHUD not save the property variables (NULL)

Tags: ios, objective-c, mbprogresshud

Im trying to implement loading progress by MBProgressHUD.

Here is my code:

```
//Previously defined @property(nonatomic) NSString *sec;

-(void) viewDidLoad{
    HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
    [self.view addSubview:HUD];
    HUD.delegate = self;
    [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(loadData) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];

    //testing the "return" value
    NSLog(@"%@", sec);
}

-(void) loadData{
  //get data from file named "results.csv"
    NSString *docPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *saving = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"results.csv"];

    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: saving]){
        NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:saving];
        NSString *dataResults = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:[fileHandle availableData] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [fileHandle closeFile];

        sec = dataResults;
        sec = [sec substringFromIndex: [sec length] - 20];
    }
}
```

As you can see in the "loadData" method I need to set the "sec" NSString as the content that saved in the "results.csv" file.
You can see another thing, that after the HUD code: "showWhileExecuting" I was put NSLog to test if it really gets the content of the file and it returns (NULL)!!

Before I added this HUD thing, It did get the real value from the file, but now its return null.

Off-course when I put the NSLog code line at the end of the "loadData" method, it prints a real value instead of (NULL).

So, the big problem that I cant get the variables from the HUD method.
The only solution that I was thinking of, was to create another file and there store all the new variables, but its not help's me.

Anyone know what Im talking about and can help me?

Comment: put NSLog in your load data and check what is stored in your data results variable

Comment: @NeilGaliaskarov It Prints a real value..

Comment: how do you declare sec variable?

Comment: @NeilGaliaskarov In the .h file: @property(nonatomic) NSString *sec;

Comment: @Nir This looks like it will execute super fast, are you certain you need a progress indicator ?  if you do, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

What you see is normal. Your NULL showing NSLog is executed immediately after the `showWhileExecuting` call, before the `loadData` has been scheduled to run. You should implement the delegate protocol `MBProgressHUDDelegate`,

```
- (void)hudWasHidden:(MBProgressHUD *)hud{
    NSLog(@"%@", sec);
}
```

When `loadData` completes, the HUD will hide, and call this method. That is when the result of `loadData` is available to you.

obcit: not tested, from memory, with an 'antique' MBProgressHUD , but a good chance it should work for you.